# Executing a shell scripts always returns null in Java

Tags: java, file, shell

I have a shell script file called `test.sh` in the home directory `~`. I want to execute the shell file using java. I use the following code:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process process = null;
        String cmd[] = {"/bin/bash","~/test.sh"};
        String[] env = {"PATH=/bin:/usr/bin/"};

        try
        {
            process = runtime.exec(cmd,env);
            process.waitFor();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            String line = reader.readLine();
            stringBuilder.append(line);

            System.out.println("The token is " + stringBuilder.toString() );

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

When I try to execute the following program, I get `null` as result like:

```
The token is null
```

where I'm making the mistake?

#### Edit:

`test.sh` has only

```
echo "Hello"
```

Comment: Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Comment: Let's see your shell script.

Comment: edited the question with test.sh file

Comment: Your code works for me in cygwin. Try reading from the error stream, see if there are any problems there, but I doubt it for such a simple script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read from the stream while the process is alive. It doesn't make sense to access getInputStream after waitFor() returns because the process had died by then. You should start a thread to read getInputStream().

Something like:

```
process = runtime.exec(cmd,env);

final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (process.getInputStream()));
final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

new Thread () {
    public void run () {
        String line = reader.readLine();
        stringBuilder.append(line);
    }
}.start ();
process.waitFor();
```